# Teaching tools (looking for a program to control what the students are doing in real time)

Tags: windows, gratis, python, programming

I am teaching how to code Python at a high school and I wanted to know if there's some software I could use to control what the students are doing in real time. I only want to watch their screens in real time, I don't need to interact with them or something more. I would need a free software, because we don't have a budget for this.

Comment: Did you find VNC during your research?

Comment: I did, but I need it to be free, and as I know VNC is not.

Comment: There are commercial VNC implementations (like RealVNC) but also free VNC version (like UltraVNC or TightVNC). But something like the suggested Veyon is definitely suited better for teachers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should checkout [Veyon](https://veyon.io/).

It's open source, available for both Windows and Linux, it does more than you need but those extra features are handy and won't cost you anything.

[image]

You can simple monitor what the students are doing, but also broadcast your own screen. 
[image: Monitor multiple student screens]

Comment: And it's even [open source](https://github.com/veyon/veyon) (GPL2), cool!

Comment: Wow. That looks impressive. I'll try that, too.

Comment: It's perfect. Is the thing I was looking for. Amazing! thanks for your response :D